# Changing texture parameters at runtime

Tags: c++, opengl

I am an OpenGL beginner and I have built a small engine for a universitary course. Now one constraint/feature I need to implement is to change the texture quality (interpolation) at runtime.

So instead of e.g.:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

it should be changed to mipmaps

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR)
```

Now I have a Texture class that abstracts this and loads an image and creates an ID for the texture etc.

What I would do: I'd bind all the textures in the game one by one and set the parameters again.

Or is there a more advanced or even faster way to do this, if I want to effect all the textures?

Comment: up until openGL 4.4 I think your method is correct.

Comment: If this is a labcourse at the Vienna UT, then this is exactly what we expect you to do :).

Comment: @BDL Wouldn't the answer of Reto Koradi be an even better solution? :)

Comment: Yes, it definitely is, and if you have time you may implementiert it. I just wanted to say, that your first solution is also fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OpenGL 3.2 and higher, there are texture **sampler** objects, which can override the sampling parameters in the textures themselves. You could use them here.

It will be particularly convenient if you want all of your textures to use the same sampling parameters. You could then just create a single sampler:

```
GLuint samplerId = 0;
glGenSamplers(1, &samplerId);
glSamplerParameteri(samplerId, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

You can then always bind this single sampler object, in addition to your regular texture binding, when texturing. Or even keep it bound all the time if you really have only one of them, and want to use it all the time:

```
glBindSampler(GL_TEXTURE_2D, samplerId);
```

Then you can change the sampling attributes with a single call:

```
glSamplerParameteri(samplerId, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

If a sampler is bound, its parameters override the corresponding values in the currently bound texture. Or in the words of the spec:

> When a sampler object is bound to a texture unit, its state supersedes that of the texture object bound to that texture unit. If the sampler name zero is bound to a texture unit, the currently bound texture’s sampler state becomes active.